# Need help regarding htaccess stuff

Tags: php, .htaccess, subdomain, redirection

I have my site at **www.example.com** and have several sub-domains city wise. Suppose i have subdomain with name say "**subdomain.example.com**" then i want to redirect the subdomain homepage to directory in same subdomain like "**subdomain.example.com/browse/city/**" so whenever user try to browse "**subdomain.example.com**" it will get redirect to "**subdomain.example.com/browse/city/**"

my site generate the pages and directory virtually, in real its not exist. like in above example "browse" and "city" is virtual directory and its fetched from database and created in real time. How can i redirect "**subdomain.example.com**" to "**subdomain.example.com/browse/city/**" through htaccess. Please let me know solve this issue, i tried googling it but didn't get anything to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a need to use `.htaccess`, don't do it.

In the server or `<VirtualHost>` context, you'll want this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/$ /browse/city/ [R=301,L]
```

Or in a `<Directory>` or `.htaccess` context that applies to the document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ browse/city/ [R=301,L]
```